# Powershell ToString() behaviour - replacing 0 in a string during ForEach-Object {$_.ToString('test_0')}

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I've encountered some Powershell behaviour that I didn't expect while using `ForEach-Object` and `ToString`. Digits are being replaced automatically and I can't quite graps the rule for the substitution from the output alone.

Here's a small simplified example:

```
PS C:\Users\Telefonmann> 1..3 | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString('test_0_1')}
test_1_1
test_2_1
test_3_1

PS C:\Users\Telefonmann> 1..3 | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString('test_0_0')}
test_0_1
test_0_2
test_0_3

PS C:\Users\Telefonmann> 1..3 | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString("test_0$_\_0")}
test_01_1
test_02_2
test_03_3

PS C:\Users\Telefonmann> 1..3 | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString("test_0$_\_$_")}
test_11_1
test_22_2
test_33_3
```

In the first example the 0 is replaced, in the second only the last 0, in the third the placeholder and the 0 are replaced and in the last example the 0 and, of course, the placeholders are replaced.
Does Powershell just see a string with a 0 and then assumes that the last 0 in any string is supposed to be a counter?

What's the term for this behaviour / is there some documentation for it?
How do I disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not Powershell doing. `.ToString` is a .net method.

You can "disable it" by not using the parameter, which is for formatting.

> #### ToString(IFormatProvider)
>
> Converts the numeric value of this instance
> to its equivalent string representation using the specified
> culture-specific format information.

You are formatting your integer into a string using the IformatProvider .net interface, which is responsible for the behaviors you are seeing.

To apply modifications in your string, simply do something like this.

```
1..3 | ForEach-Object { ("test_0_$_") }
```

**References**

[.Net - Formatting types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types)

[Int32.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 2):

An idiom like to generate computernames is:

```
1..3 | % tostring comp000

comp001
comp002
comp003
```

You can escape a code with a backslash like in this ip address example:

```
1..3 | % tostring 192\.168\.\0\.0

192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```